# Distribution of a dense subset in an interval

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

This is a very general question. Given a bounded interval $I$, such as $[0,1]$, and an open dense subset $D \subset I$ such that $m(D \cap I) < 1/2 \cdot m(I)$(say), can we say anything interesting about $m(D \cap I')$ in terms of $m(I')$ for any subinterval $I' \subset I$? in particular a similar upper bound for $m(D \cap I')$ in terms of the length $m(I')$.

Comment: Can a dense open subset of a bounded interval have measure less than the measure of the interval?

Answer (score 0):

No and here is a counterexample. Let $I=[0,1]$ and $I_n=[\frac{1}{2^{n-1}},\frac{1}{2^n}]$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$. Our strategy will be to define open dense subsets $D_n\subset I_n$ such that $m(D_n)=\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$. In this case, $m(D)=m(\bigcup_n D_n)=\frac{1}{2}m(I)$ (we can easily adjust to get an inequality at the end). We can then cut each $I_n$ into two pieces: the top piece $I^1_n=[\frac{1}{2^{n-1}},\frac{3}{2^{n+1}}]$ and the bottom piece $I^2_n=(\frac{3}{2^{n+1}},\frac{1}{2^n}]$. You can check that this splits each interval exactly in half, since we cut at its midpoint. When defining each $D_n$, we can choose a proportion of $D_n$ to split between $I^1_n$ and $I^2_n$, i.e. some $r$ such that $m(D_n\cap I^1_n)/m(I^1_n)=r$ and $m(D_n\cap I^2_n)/m(I^2_n)=1-r$. Think of this as the percentage of $D_n$ inside $I^1_n$ and the percentage of $D_n$ inside $I^2_n$; since $m(I^1_n)=m(I^2_n)=m(D_n)$, we can have at most $100$% of $D_n$ in the top half $I^1_n$ and $0$% in the second half $I^2_n$, or any other such split where each halves add to the total $100$% of the measure of $D_n$.

Because there are countably many intervals $I_n$, we can index the rational numbers in the set $[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ as $r_1,r_2,...$ and associate the each $r_n$ to the system $I^1_n$, $I^2_n$ and $D_n$ as is done above with "$r$". In this case, we get for any rational proportion $r\in[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}$, there is some interval $I_n$ with $m(D_n\cap I^1_n)/m(I^1_n)=r$. Letting $D$ be the open dense subset $\bigcup_n D_n\subset I$, this completes the counterexample.

To ensure that $m(D)=m(\bigcup_n D_n)<\frac{1}{2}m(I)$, we can choose the interval $D_n$ associated to the ratio $r=1$ (i.e. with $m(D_n\cap I^1_n)/m(I^1_n)=1$ and $m(D_n\cap I^2_n)/m(I^2_n)=0$) and shrink both $I^1_n$ and $D_n$, while expanding $I^2_n$ so that we still have i) $I_n=I^1_n\sqcup I^2_n$, ii) $m(D_n\cap I^1_n)/m(I^1_n)=1$, and iii) $m(D_n\cap I^2_n)/m(I^2_n)=0$. In this case $m(D_n)<\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$, and consequently total measure has the property $m(D)=m(\bigcup_n D_n)<\frac{1}{2}m(I)$.

I hope I was as clear as possible with my reasoning and explanation, but drawing out this solution will help greatly if there's any confusion about the proof or its motivation!

Comment: The motivation for this problem is to understand the solution of problem 8 here: http://www.math.utah.edu/~ptrapa/6210/ps2-solutions.pdf. By the iterative construction provided there, I am able to show that $m(E \cap I') > 0$ for any subinterval $I' \subset I$, but not the other half of the inequality $m(E \cap I') < |I'|$.

Comment: I see the context now. Make sure you agree with the statement that $E$ in the solution has measure $2\epsilon$. From here, since the solution has to do with filling the "holes" in each $E_i$ stage to get to stage $E_{i+1}$, the symmetric nature of this procedure should fill each "hole" in $E_i$ with a construction similar to the totality of $E$ itself. You can then argue that each hole in $E_i$ is filled with something of measure less than the hole's length. Each interval $I$ must contain some hole in some stage $E_i$, and thus $E\cap I$ is missing measure from this hole and $m(E\cap I)<m(I)$.

Comment: That $E$ has less than full measure in $I$ is evident enough. The difficulty is to demonstrate the same for any random subinterval $I' \subset I$. Start with a compact subset $K \subset I$ with the property that $m(K \cap J) < |J|$ for any interval $J$(Here we let our $K$ to be the complement $I \setminus D$, where $D \subset I$ is an open dense subset). $I \setminus K$ is open and thus an at most countable union of open intervals(holes), fill in each of these holes as above and iterate. I want to show that the end result $E$ will have the given property.

Comment: There are two points I can clarify from my last reply that might help! In each "hole" $H$ from stage $E_i$, the completed iterative process fills $H$ with a construction that mirrors the construction of $E$ itself. In other words $E\cap H$, the filled (at the end of the iteration) hole, can be seen to have measure less than that of $H$ for the same reason that $E$ has measure less than $I$. The second point is notation: to match your notation, the end of my previous comment should say "Each subinterval $I'\subset I$ must contain some hole in..." Do you see the solution from this?

Comment: The issue is that the holes are shrinking in size and is chained together. Namely, $I' \setminus E_1 \supset I' \setminus E_1 \setminus E_2 \supset \ldots I' \setminus E_1 \setminus \ldots E_n \supset \ldots$. If $n$ is the first natural number such that $m(I' \setminus E_1 \setminus \ldots E_n) < |I'|$, then $0 < m(I' \cap E_n) < |I'|$. In fact, $E_n$ partially fills the hole $I' \setminus E_1 \setminus \ldots \setminus E_{n-1}$. But then it is unclear whether the part of $I'$ not filled by $E_n$, is filled completely in the remaining process by $E_{n+1}, E_{n+2}, \ldots$, etc.

Comment: It will thus be convenient for the sequence of the size of holes $m(I' \setminus E_1 \setminus \ldots \setminus E_n)$ to be bounded away from $0$, by upper bounding the size of the corresponding fillings $m(I' \cap E_n)$ in terms of the remaining length. This is the reason for the question in the original post.

Comment: It seems like the argument does show that the part of $I'$ not filled in by $E_n$ is filled partially in the remaining stages of the construction  so that any subinterval $I''\subset I'$ has the property that $m(E\cap I'')<m(I'')$. Since $I'$ was an arbitrary subinterval of $I$ the same argument would serve to show that $I''$ has this property; if we can establish the result for an arbitrary subinterval $I'$ of $I$, this allows us to conclude the result for all subintervals of $I$. Maybe I'm misunderstanding your comments, does this address your concerns?

Comment: If $H_n$ is a hole that appears for the first time at stage $n$, then at stage $n+1$ it is filled with some Cantor-like set with nonzero measure so that  $m(H_n\cap E_{n+1})<m(H_n)$. Any further holes that we have now introduced into $H_n\cap E_{n+1}$ are then filled by the construction in stage $n+2$ in the same way.

Comment: I appreciate your constant feedback, so let me clarify the point of issue a bit further. For a given subinterval $I’ \subset I$, the “holes” $H_n$ in the $n$th stage of our construction is the set $I’ \setminus E_1 \setminus \ldots \setminus E_n$, to be “filled” partially by another cantor-like copy $E_{n+1}$.  Since we define $E$ to be the union of these fillings $\cup_n E_n$, to ensure $m(E \cap I’) < |I’|$, we need $m(I’ \setminus E) > 0$. Hence the sequence $m(I’ \setminus E_1 \setminus \ldots \setminus E_n)$ need not only be positive for all $n$, but actually be bounded away from $0$.

Comment: You are correct that we need $m(I'\setminus E)>)$ and hence the sequence you mention must be bounded away from $0$. This is where we can look by analogy to how we designed $m(I\setminus E)>0$ by letting $m(E)=2\epsilon$. If we build this sequence in a "fractal-like" way, we can ensure that each hole is filled with something resembling the entirety of $E$, and thus that it is filled with something that converges in a controlled manner.

Comment: For clarity of notation, let each stage $H_n$ be disjoint from the prior stages; in the notation of the pdf, this would technically be $H_n \setminus H_{n−1}$. Then $m(E_n)=\frac{\epsilon}{2^{n-1}}$. Let $H_{n,i}$ be the countable set of holes in stage $n$ of the construction to be filled by $E_n$, indexed by $i$. We can disperse the measure $m(E_n)$ over each of these holes $H_{n,i}$ by filling each $H_{n,i}$ with a cantor set of measure $m(H_{n,i})\cdot \frac{\epsilon}{2^{n-1}}$. Think of this as filling each $H_{n,i}$ with its own "mini" version of $E_n$, scaled to fit into $H_{n,i}$.

Comment: Letting $E_n$ be the union of each of the cantor sets we used to fill the $H_{n,i}$s, you can check that $m(E_n)=\frac{\epsilon}{2^{n-1}}$. The act of filling each $H_{n,i}$ with a "mini" version of $E_n$ establishes the analogy between the total construction of $E$ and the construction of a mini version of the tail $E_n\cup E_{n+1}\cup...$ of $E$ scaled to fit inside $H_{n,i}$. This gives us that $m(E\cap H_{n,i})=m(H_{n,i})\cdot\frac{2\epsilon}{2^{n-1}}=m(H_{n,i})\cdot\frac{\epsilon}{2^{n-2}}$.

Comment: We can verify our work a bit by noting that $\bigcup_i(E\cap H_{n,i})=E_n\cup E_{n+1}\cup...$ and that the above calculations correctly give that $m(\bigcup_i(E\cap H_{n,i}))=m(E_n\cup E_{n+1}\cup...)=\frac{\epsilon}{2^{n-2}}$. When added to $m(E_1\cup...\cup E_{n-1})=\epsilon+\frac{\epsilon}{2}+...+\frac{\epsilon}{2^{n-2}}$, we get the total measure $m(E)=2\epsilon$, as we had intended.